# Slow installation of python/django packages in aws lightsail

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have been trying to install some python packages in lightsail but it has been slow mainly taking more than 8 hours thus far.
I have used `pip install -r mypiplistreq.txt` after long hours I used `pip3 install -r mypiplistreq.txt` it was still the same result,
the pip comes up with the message**S** such as

```
`INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of urllib3/[PACKAGE_NAME] to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.`
`INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking`
```

And it then downloads different versions of .whl or tar.gz files some of them numbering over 15 versions with different file sizes in Kb and Mb

There have been many such messages mostly for packages which I did not even specify in my requirements list.

This has made my installation to take hours on `lightsail` using `bitnami` for `django`. What can I do to improve its installation.

I hope that I have made my side really clear. if there is any need for further clarity please let me know